# D3 x-axis date not showing for Sundays

Tags: d3.js, charts

I'm using the code below to display the day of the week and the month value for my data. D3 displays the date as expected e.g. "Sat 18" but for Sunday it shows the month instead e.g. "Oct 19"!

Can't figure out why this is happening. The code is:

```
 var xScale = d3.time.scale()
        .domain([new Date($scope.dataset[0][0].time),d3.time.day.offset(new Date($scope.dataset[0][$scope.dataset[0].length-2].time),2)])
        .rangeRound([0, w-0]);
 var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale)
        .orient('bottom')
        .ticks(d3.time.days,1);
```

Any ideas why this is happening? the sample dataset looks like this:

{time: "2014-10-19",y: 0,y0: 0}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, D3 will apply some adaptive formatting to the date tick values (see ["This set of time intervals is somewhat arbitrary and additional values may be added in the future" section](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales#ticks)), but you can override this with a specific date format, for example:

```
.ticks(d3.time.days,1)
.tickFormat(d3.time.format('%a %e'));
```

You can find the remainder of the formatting options [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#format).

Comment: Thanks that worked, I wasnt adding the tickFormat method properly